# ios turn locationServicesEnabled off in code

Tags: ios, unit-testing

I am writing unit tests and i want to test with `CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled` set ON and OFF, without having to change setting on the simulator.

Is there a way to set `locationServicesEnabled` in code?

[Apple CLLocationManager docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can alter the simulator settings in code but you can obviously start / stop your own app's checking of location updates:

Start location updates in code:

`[CLLocationManager startUpdatingLocation]`

Stop location updates in code:

`[CLLocationManager stopUpdatingLocation]`

Answer (score 0):

By Enable

```
[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]
```